# How to access method from imported class?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have a class `Scroller`:

```
class Scroller {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    scroll() {
        alert("this works");
    }

}

module.exports = Scroller;
```

imported into my app file...

```
import '../css/main.scss';
import { nodes } from './nodes';
import { Scroller } from './scrolling';

const s = new Scroller; 

nodes.nav.addEventListener('click', () => {
    s.scroll();
});
```

Why won't this console log 'this works' when I click on the nav?

PS I know for sure the event listener is set up the right way, the problem is using that method...

Comment: brilliant - thank you. Slightly ashamed...trust that I did try and sort it out for about an hour...

Comment: You mix `require()`JS style with the `import` syntax. Decide for one

Comment: Omitting the brackets in a constructor call without arguments is valid syntax, and works identically to adding them.

Comment: Didn't you mean to tag typescript instead of javascript?

Comment: @J.Pichardo wrong, you don't need them

Comment: What is a syntax error however is the following: "SyntaxError: super() is only valid in derived class constructors", which you should read in your console.

Comment: @ASDFGerte ok so I tried using export default class Scroller, now I'm getting warnings in the console

Comment: @ASDFGerte I'm getting a complaint from Webpack: 
WARNING in ./src/js/app.js 5:14-22
"export 'Scroller' was not found in './scrolling'

Comment: @ASDFGerte even though it's definitely there and it's the right directory

Answer (score 1):

In addition to fixing the parentheses, a problem is

```
module.exports = Scroller;
```

You're exporting `Scroller` as the *default export*, but

```
import { Scroller } from './scrolling';
```

you're trying to import it as a *named import*. But no such named import exists on `scrolling`'s exports. Import the *default* object from `./scrolling` instead:

```
import Scroller from './scrolling';
```

Comment: Working! Thanks... need to brush up on my import/export syntax obviously...